# android kernel ‘rnd’ may be used uninitialized error when compiling

Tags: android, linux, makefile

hi guys i have started to download and compile a kernel for my device(Moto g5S plus aka sanders)
and everything went well until make clean and make mrproper commands which just threw me this

```
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
```

but i ignored it and continued to progress through and after executing the command make defconf

```
 make sanders_defconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.hash.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
  arch/x86/configs/sanders_defconfig:438:warning: override: reassigning to symbol KSM
 #
# configuration written to .config
#
```

as you see i got a warning but again i ignored it ! But the real problem arouse in the final step i.e make command which threw me this

```
CC      arch/x86/mm/mmap.o
arch/x86/mm/mmap.c: In function ‘arch_mmap_rnd’:
arch/x86/mm/mmap.c:82:13: error: ‘rnd’ may be used uninitialized in this function[-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  return rnd << PAGE_SHIFT;
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:265: recipe for target 'arch/x86/mm/mmap.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/mm/mmap.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:410: recipe for target 'arch/x86/mm' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/mm] Error 2
Makefile:981: recipe for target 'arch/x86' failed
make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
```

any help will be massively appreciated. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original poster does not need the answer any more, but I ran into the same issue. After some time, I figured out from the Makefile, that you need to add this make arg to your make command, or script: CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE=y
So it will trigger the build flags around line 625 in Makefile:

```
ifdef CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -Os $(call cc-disable-warning,maybe-uninitialized,)
else
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -O2
endif
```